# Make email read using Gmail IMAP via PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, imap, gmail-imap, php-imap

I have a use case to fetch email attachments. I got this code from GitHub: [imap-gmail](https://gist.github.com/AikChun/8305789).

Here this will extract attachments from all emails, but I need to make email read every time I check for attachments, and extract attachments only from new emails next time. And I need to select only pdf, doc and docx files. Also I need to append the email of the sender to the attachment file name.

How to make emails read while looping through each mail to fetch email attachments?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for unread mails:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
```

and made email read at the end:

```
imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen");
```